# Image source UriKind

Tags: c#, wpf, image, uri

I have a project it's name is 'xx'.
I create a folder "images" that have this path :
xx\bin\Debug\images\

images contain only one photo it's name is "1.jpg"
the MainWindow contain Image control;
I set this code to load the image source but it doesn't work why ??:

```
private void Image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Image i = sender as Image; ;
    BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"images\1.jpg",UriKind.Relative));
    i.Source=b;
}
```

How can I load the Image source by code ??
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `1.jpg` to your project in the `images` folder and [set the Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66.aspx) of `1.jpg` to **Resource**. To load the resource, use the [packURI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069) conventions.

```
private void Image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Image i = sender as Image; ;
    BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/" 
         + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name 
         + ";component/" 
         + "Images/1.jpg", UriKind.Absolute)); 
    i.Source=b;
}
```

Comment: i added this folder and 1.jpg to it manualy from window explorer , not from the solution of my project

Comment: Best practices is to add it to your project and set **copy always**. This way it will always get copied to the output (debug/release) folder and will be managed by source control.

Comment: System.Windows.Controls.Image doesn't contain static method (FromFile)
note : my project is wpf project

Comment: Your question wasn't tagged as **WPF**, sorry for the confusion. See edits above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void Image_MouseDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
    dlg.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    dlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();                        

    if (result == true)
    {
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        Image img = sender as Image;
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(dlg.FileName);
        bitmap.EndInit();
        img.Source = bitmap;
    }
}
```